# How to distribute multiple variants of a cocoa framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, frameworks

I've got a Cocoa framework that I want to distribute. For people who don't want to pull it in as a submodule and build it themselves, I'd like to provide a pre-built version: ECLogging.framework.

The wrinkle is that the framework has Debug/Release variants that have different behaviour (not just different compiler options, but potentially actually executing different code).

What's the most idiomatic way to distribute this, and for people to set up their Xcode projects?

I want people to be able to do #import , so I can't rename the debug version of the framework as ECLoggingDebug.framework (for example).

So I can give them the frameworks in a folder like this:
ECLogging/
  Debug/
    ECLogging.framework
  Release/
    ECLogging.framework

It's easy enough for people to then set up a framework search path ECLogging/$(CONFIGURATION)/, which will pick up the correct one.

This works fine during compiling and linking, but you also need to embed the right version into the built app.

In a Copy Files phase (the normal way to do the embedding), Xcode wants to know where it really is, and I don't think I can somehow use environment variables to tell it.

I can write a script instead, of course, which just copies it. I'm fine with that, but it seems clumsy to have to ask users of the framework to do this.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do the debug and release versions *need* to have different compiler settings (when you build them), or is different behavior the essential thing?

Comment: In general the only compiler options differences are the normal symbols/optimisation settings. It would probably be acceptable to have the pre-built version just use release settings.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding the scenario correctly, here's what I'd do. I'd make only one version of the framework. Instead of making the behavior of the framework depend on compile-time debug/release configurations (presumably using #ifdefs, etc.), I'd use a (Framework) global variable to indicate debug vs release mode. I'd add a simple method to turn debug mode on (e.g. `[ECLogging setDebugModeEnabled:YES]`) that users can call upon launch to change the framework's behavior. Then, it's as easy for them as:

```
#if DEBUG
[ECLogging setDebugModeEnabled:YES];
#endif
```

Comment: Normally that's what I'd do too, but in this particular case there might be performance implications. I think I may well have to go down that route though.

Comment: I'm curious about the possible performance implications. A conditional that checks the value of a global `DebugModeEnabled` variable should be quite fast...

Comment: Actually, I simplified slightly, it's not just about performance. There are other reasons why you might want to actually exclude code - for example a debug version of a framework might want to use some undocumented/private API that a release version absolutely mustn't use.